# Jscape Resume Upload

Tags: java, sftp

I have a question regarding resume upload method used in `com.jscape.inet.sftp.Sftp` class.

As per API, in the method below, the second argument is `localFileOffset`.

```
resumeUpload(java.lang.String localFile, long localFileOffset)
```

How is the `localFileOffset` calculated? I assume the `localFileOffset` should be the point from where the upload should continue which is basically the file size of the file already uploaded in bytes.

Something like below:

```
Boolean isRemoteFileAvailable = sftp.isValidPath(uploadDir + "/" + RemoteFileName);

if (isRemoteFileAvailable)
{
    remoteFileSize = sftp.getFilesize(rrFileName);
    localFileOffset = remoteFileSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hit and trial and several round of testing here is my conclusion.

As per API below is the method definition:
resumeUpload(java.io.File localFile, long localFileOffset)

If you use localFileOffset which will be (local file size - Remote file size), you end up loosing data.

The 2nd argument is definitely not local file offset but it is remote file size in bytes which is calculated as sftp.getFilesize(remoteFile);

I have tested my code several time by stopping and using resume upload multiple times and compared the original file with the uploaded file. There was no difference and the last resume upload completed within seconds thereby confirming it is resuming from where it finished instead of uploading from scratch.